# What's wrong with my monitor?

Tags: display, troubleshooting

I have a 19" SyncMaster 912N from 2004.  After being on for a while, every other column of pixels goes black.  It goes away when the monitor is unplugged for a while.  What is wrong with it?  Is it repairable?

Edit: It is the LCD, since it has happened with multiple PCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using it frequently lately without issue.  It may have been a cable problem, but I am also turning off the monitor when not in use.

Answer (score 2):

It is repairable - you will need to find out if it is the control board or the panel itself... however, as others have said it will most likely cost more for replacement parts than just getting a new screen.

I would check if you still have warranty, or any rights - some branded monitors have 5 years, but you would be at the limit so be quick!

Comment: its probably after the warranty, as it was bought in July of 2004

Comment: It is also likely to cost far more to repair than to just buy a new monitor.  That tends to be the case with LCD monitors and TVs

Comment: @BBlake: We have been having a LOT of trouble at work with LCD monitors lately - in most cases the monitor is 3~5 years old, and *every* case has been due to capacitor plague http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague which is very cheap and easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be repairable.

But first be sure that it's the (LCD) monitor, and not the video card.